# sum all values of a particular key in arraylist android

Tags: android, arraylist

Am having an arraylist

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
```

and am adding json data to this arraylist to populate in listview later, using hashmap in the below format

```
                   int ja=jsonarray.length();

            for (int i = 0; i <= ja; i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects

                map.put("slno", jsonobject.getString("slno"));
                map.put("mark", jsonobject.getString("mark"));


                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);

            }
```

the problem is I want to calculate all the **mark** values and populate in a textview as total marks. how shall I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the best way to do, but it will definitely give you the solution.

```
try{
   int sum = 0;
   for(HashMap<String, String> map : arrayList) {
      sum += Integer.parseInt(map.get("mark"));
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
   //Manage your exception
}
// sum has the value for the marks total.
System.out.println("Total Marks: "+sum);
```

Comment: am getting 0 as output

Comment: Could you please post your complete code in your question. Also could you check if you are getting back values for the marks in the JSON?

Comment: am getting value of marks.. shall i use your solution inside arrayadapter or in postexecute?

Comment: sorry!!! it worked. due to float numbers may be it was not showing the desired result.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to go through the `ArrayList` and find the "mark" key from
your `HashMap` and add it to the total sum.

```
    int nTotalSum = 0;

    try
    {

      for( int i =0; i < arraylist.size(); i++ )
      {
        HashMap<String, String> map = arraylist.get(i);
        String sValue;
        if ( (sValue=map.get("mark")) != null)
        {
          nTotalSum += Integer.parseInt(sValue);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    System.out.println("Total Mark: " + nTotalSum);
```

Comment: shall i use this inside postexecute or in arrayadapter?

Comment: you can use it either. it really depends on how big is the size of your ArrayList. If it is less than 100 then you can put it anywhere but if you will be processing many entries like thousands then a Thread or in the doInBackground might be a good choice.